# XSLT: Subtotals

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

Source XML:

```
<Root>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>B</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>C</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>5</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>B</Code>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>C</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>B</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>A</Code>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Code>C</Code>
        <Value>5</Value>
    </Data>
....
</Root>
```

XSL-FO Code:

My code(XSL-FO) contains 3 columns where each column contains the content of 'A', 'B', 'C'

```
<fo:table-body>
    <xfd:table-row-repeat xpath="Root/Data" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="10pt" padding-after="0.55cm">
        <xsl:if test="Code='A'">
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt">Value
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="Value" /> 
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block> 
        </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:if>
    </xfd:table-row-repeat>
</fo:table-body>
```

Same code for each columns to display values of 'B' & 'C'
In Table-footer i've to get these subtotal of 'A','B', 'C'

```
<fo:table-body>
    <xfd:table-row-repeat xpath="Root/Data" font-family="Arial Narrow" font-size="10pt" padding-after="0.55cm">
        <xsl:if test="Code='A'">
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt">SubTotal
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center">
            <--Here Sum of first 15 A's. if the A's or B's or C's exceed by 15, then the table flows to 2nd Page. In that case, 1st Page table-footer shows individual subtotals of first 15 A's, 15 B's and C's. In 2nd Page, the subtotals should contain Subtotal of first 15 A's+ Succeeding A's, in the same way B's and C's --> 
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block> 
        </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:if>
    </xfd:table-row-repeat>
</fo:table-body>
```

Here the XSL-FO code is shown for only one column(For Root/Data/Code='A'), the other 2 columns('B' & 'C') consists of same code.

Conditions in Detail:

```
Condition 1): when Root/Data/Code = 'A' or 'B' or 'C'
   i need individual totals of 'A', 'B' and 'C' in Table-Footer individual Column.

Condition 2): inturn if individual count(Root/Data/Code) of 'A', 'B' & 'C' crosses 15.          Then Page flows to 2nd Page then Table-Footer in 2nd Page needs to contains subtotal of first 15 A's + the sum of succeeding A's in the same way for B's And C's
```

i.e., if 20 A's, 10 B's and 25 C's are present in Source XML.

```
In 1st Page, Table-Footer

SubtotalI(Value of 15 A's)=
SubtotalII(Value 10 B's)=   
SubtotalIII(Value 15 C's)=

In 2nd Page, Table-Footer

SubtotalI(15 A's+ next 5 A's)=   
SubtotalII(Value 10 B's)= <!--No Change as count of B's is less than 15 -->
SubtotalIII(15 C's + next 10 C's)=
```

I'm trying this logic using xsl:key by grouping through **Code tag** for evaluating sum of 'A', 'B' and 'C'. As i'm new to XSLT i'm finding it too difficult to solve this logic using xsl:key. Can anyone help in solving this logic?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is *not* something you should be doing in XSLT! XSL transforms are great for transforming the structure of documents. They are not very good for applying logic and conditional computation.

Comment: Could you please restate your question? It's unclear what you are expecting to get.

Comment: I've made my question much clearer. check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several difficulties with what you try to achieve. Calculating subtotals at a given point is easiest actually. You just need the preceding axis and a sum to calculate it:

```
sum(preceding::Value[../Code = 'A'])
```

To include the current value as well, use the union operator like this:

```
sum(Value[../Code = 'A'] | preceding::Value[../Code = 'A'])
```

A bigger difficulty is to show a different table 'footer' on each page. Headers and footers are repeated on pages automatically, but the contents is the same across all pages which the table spans. The only solution I see is to break the table yourself, adding a different table footer each time.

By far the easiest way is to just take a fixed number of Data elements at a time, and displaying those in a separate table. You can loop through A, B and C types in one for-each, giving each value a separate row. That way the table always has the same number of rows. You can experiment with the number you can include to determine how many fit on one page.

The following code returns a table with the first 10 Data values. A, B and C values are positioned straight under each other, but you could position them left, middle, and right respectively if you like. At the bottom of the table three rows are added with subtotals for A, B and C.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="global">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="global">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="150mm" border-style="solid">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="50mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="50mm"/>
                            <fo:table-column column-width="50mm"/>

                            <fo:table-body font-size="7pt">
                                <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Data[10 >= position()]">
                                    <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                        <fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:block height="12pt">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Code" />
                                            </fo:block> 
                                        </fo:table-cell> 
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center"> 
                                                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />  
                                            </fo:block> 
                                        </fo:table-cell> 
                                        <fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block>  
                                        </fo:table-cell> 
                                    </fo:table-row>

                                    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                                        <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Subtotal A</fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center"> 
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding::Value[../Code = 'A'] | Value[../Code = 'A'])" />  
                                                </fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block>  
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Subtotal B</fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center"> 
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding::Value[../Code = 'B'] | Value[../Code = 'B'])" />  
                                                </fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block>  
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Subtotal C</fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block height="12pt" border="0.1pt solid black" text-align="center"> 
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding::Value[../Code = 'C'] | Value[../Code = 'C'])" />  
                                                </fo:block> 
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                            <fo:table-cell> 
                                                <fo:block height="12pt">Points</fo:block>  
                                            </fo:table-cell> 
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </fo:table-body>
                        </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>

        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You still need something to determine how many tables of n Data items you would need, and then do some recursive calls to output all of them. Hope this is sufficient for the moment to get you going again!

PS: I noticed you are using xfd prefix. That looks like you are working with the XF Designer from Ecrion. I am not very familiar with it. The above code is a plain XSLT 1.0 solution. Not sure it works in XF Designer, please let me know..

Comment: @BVS Silly me, I am totally forgetting fo:marker. It should be possible to put fo:marker's in each table cell containing the running total of A, B and C (separate marker-class-name's). You should be able to use fo:retrieve-table-marker to pull the last marker value of current page into the table-footer. I tried to change my example, but FOP doesn't seem to support this. So could be worth a try, but you may find out your processor doesn't support it either. HTH!